# Union of Countable Sets is Countable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{E_n\}$, $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, be a sequence of countable sets, and put $S = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$. Prove that $S$ is countable.

Comment: (Are we assuming the sets $E_n$ are all infinite? Otherwise, this is not quite a duplicate of the linked question.)

Comment: @Andres: It appears to be quoted verbatim from Baby Rudin, which defines *countable* to mean *countably infinite*, so the assumption is probably justified. If not, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41968/cardinality-of-infinite-family-of-finite-sets?rq=1) covers the countably infinite union of non-empty finite sets.